# Angular 14 The animation trigger "rootItem" has built with the following warnings: - The following provided properties are not animatable: overflow

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-animations

Updated to Angular 14 and this warning appeared. These properties are not used in my animations.

```
[Error in console][1]
The animation trigger "rootItem" has built with the following warnings:
 - The following provided properties are not animatable: overflow
   (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)
The animation trigger "panelContent" has built with the following warnings:
 - The following provided properties are not animatable: overflow
The animation trigger "submenu" has built with the following warnings:
 - The following provided properties are not animatable: overflow
```

How fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is in the warnings: you can't animate the CSS `overflow` property. Stop trying to do so, and the warnings will go away: use `ngClass` or `ngStyle` if you need to programmatically modify an element's `overflow` property

Comment: Can you look at the compiled code to find what is trying to animate overflow. Overflow is discretely animatable so it’s a bit surprising to get a warning like that.

Comment: @WillAlexander The overflow property is not used anywhere in my project at all. Checked through the search for the project.
But it is in the libraries. Added search screenshot.

Comment: Are you using the PrimeNg component library? I'm seeing a similar issue

Comment: Here's a link to the relevant issue in PrimeNg- https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/11617

Comment: @DavidShortman I also use PrimeNg and see this warning

Comment: I suspect this warning is gonna go away in a near future fix, @Vega. It shows up whenever you set styles attributes that are not animable whether or not your implementation sets them as part of an animate() call in a transition. It's very common to set "preparation" styles to be applied only for the duration of a transition (absolute positioning and overflow) but animate only specific styles (such as opacity). In this example, we would not be trying to animate position and overflow, but since it is set somewhere within the transition() call, Angular 14 warns us (IMHO erroneously) about it.

Comment: I've opened an Issue at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46602

Comment: @DavidShortman PrimeNg Yes

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Solution for false-positive warnings coming possibly through [PR 46666](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46666)

---

These warnings were added on [PR 45212](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/45212) to aid with [issue 27577](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27577).

They are *dev-only* warnings that were added to "provide a better experience for developers so that if they see that something is not being animated then they can easily identify what is going wrong".

If anywhere in the transition not animatable properties are set, a warning is gonna be issued, *whether or not* they are part of an `animate()` call. You said  that you're getting warnings for properties not used in your animations, but remember that `animate()` calls that *don't* specify the properties to bet animated, only the timing (in other words, only provide the first argument), *will* animate the diff between the initial and the end states, and that might be where the non animatable properties are being noted by the compiler.

If you are certain those non animatable properties are not part of your code in any way and thus the warnings make non sense, maybe open an issue on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues and provide an implementation example?

That being said, the discussion on [issues 46602](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46602) *might* end up causing Angular to provide a way for developers to disable warnings in-place on `style()` calls where they decide the warnings are not applicable, but we'll have to wait and see.